# how to listen to a function in external js from the script in html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pygooglechart

**I want to write an event listener in the hmtl script for a function in the external javascript file **

```js
/**
 * Created by ramnath on 02-03-2016.
 */
/*chart.js*/
var merry;
merry=this;
var a=10;
function starlander(){
    var name=['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'];
    var data1=['2004',  1000,      400];
    var data2=['2005',  1170,      460];
    var data3=['2006',  660,       1120];
    var data4=['2007',  1030,      540];
    table=[name,data1,data2,data3,data4];
    console.log("control came to me");
    //drawChart(table);
    return table;
}
function Alwayschanges(){
    this.on('input',function(msg){
        msg=msg.payload;
        return msg;
    })
}


> In this html page i want to monitor the function Alawyschanges and get msg every time there is a change in Alwayschanges funciton
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function updateChart(){
            
          //event listener
            
        }
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(starlander());

            var options = {
                title: "you got me pal",
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            updateChart();
        }
        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is your function `Alwayschanges` returning msg??

Comment: I just assumed that it will return msg when its called but what i want to do is to listen Alwayschanges function in html script. So that I could call it every time there is a change in msg value

Comment: Can you make code changes in `Alwayschanges` function? do you have control over it?

Comment: No, but if there is a function(external js) which has its element value changed then I want to monitor that change from html script. In this case lets just assume if there is some other function in chart.js which is making constant changed to the Alwayschanges function.

Comment: 1 thing I can think of when we dont have control over the code is periodically check the value of that variable and trigger a alert or waht ever logic when the value changes, This might be like a check every sec. and wont trigger as soon as the variable changes, But is fast enough to make it negligible. Is this kind of solution ok for you?

Comment: great! where is like button when you need one !!

Comment: I didnt get you, But it sounded like a compliment :)

Comment: Can you provide the logic ? please remember that the variable is in the external js file and trigger is in html file